# What is "Passive mode" in File Connector in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

[File Connector configuration in WSO2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkQnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

this is connected to 'FTP passive mode', so if you are writing to a local file system it is not applicable. In passive mode, the client initiates all connections to prevent firewall issues. A good explanation can be found here: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: Hi, can you please explain about FTP passive mode? what it does?